# Setting classpath in WAS server in Linux

Tags: linux, websphere, classpath

I want to set classpath (/home/abc/xyz) in WAS V8.0.0.5 server JVM (in admin console) in a Linux machine. Does it work jsut like Windows? Or is it any different? Can you please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same on both environments (other than the differences in file/path separators - "/" & ":" vs. "\" & ";"), as the "-cp" and "-classpath" arguments are Java arguments, not OS-specific arguments, and the classpath elements in the WAS server configuration are consistent across operating systems as well.

For what it's worth, you should basically never need to edit the server JVM classpath - if you run into a situation where you think it's necessary, that probably indicates a packaging problem in your application.  Classpath entries at that level run the risk of overriding server linkages and implementation definitions, and you can make things visible to multiple applications through more manageable configurations like shared libraries.